# Firebase cloud function storage trigger first thumbnail urls are fine then the next ones are all the same thumbnails urls as the first

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to upload an image to firebase and then produce 2 thumbnails. I am able to do this with no problems. My current road block is when I write the urls to the realtime database, I am always getting the same url as the initial upload.

For example:

- 1st upload I get my uploaded image with the two proper thumbnails for the image
- 2nd upload I get my uploaded image with the two previous thumbnails (first image)
- 3rd upload I get my uploaded image with the first images thumbnails...
  ...this continues to reproduce the urls for the first upload

In my storage the correct thumbnails are being generated, but the urls are always for the first upload?

I don't know if this is a problem with the getSignedUrl() or not, really not sure whats going on here.

Here is my cloud function:

```
  export const generateThumbs = functions.storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize(async object => {
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket); // The Storage object.
    // console.log(object);
    console.log(object.name);
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

    const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
    const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, 'source.png');

    if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
      console.log('exiting function');
      return false;
    }

    // 1. ensure thumbnail dir exists
    await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

    // 2. Download Sounrce fileName
    await bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
    });

    //3. resize the images and define an array of upload promises
    const sizes = [64, 256];

    const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
      const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`;
      const thumbPath = join(workingDir, thumbName);

      //Resize source image
      await sharp(tmpFilePath)
      .resize(size, size)
      .toFile(thumbPath);

      //upload to gcs
      return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
        destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName),
        metadata: {
         contentType: 'image/jpeg'
       }
      }).then((data) => {
        const file = data[0]
        // console.log(data)
        file.getSignedUrl({
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-17-2100'
        }).then((response) => {
          const url = response[0];
          if (size === 64) {
            // console.log('generated 64');
            return admin.database().ref('profileThumbs').child(fileName).set({ thumb: url });
          } else {
            // console.log('generated 128');
            return admin.database().ref('categories').child(fileName).child('thumb').set(url);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        });
      })
    });

    //4. Run the upload operations
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    //5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
    return fs.remove(workingDir);
  })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're observing.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "I get the same thumbnails as the first one".

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi Doug, thank you I fixed my question.

Comment: It looks like you're not handling promises correctly.  Is there any reason why you are not using the promise returned by getSignedUrl instead of the callaback?  The way you have it now, the function might terminate before the database is written, as you are not waiting for getSignedUrl to complete.

Comment: @DougStevenson How can I go about doing this? would it be a matter of just attaching a .then() with the url and use it from there for my write? I'm a bit new to promises :/

Comment: See the API documentation for getSignedUrl.  There are lots of samples in it.  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#getSignedUrl

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the link. I checked it out and have been researching more about promises - I'm familiar with them when using it for various firebase tasks but I cant seem to get this working... I updated my answer with an attempt at using a promise to return the url after the operation is complete but I am still getting the same thumbnail? Can you please check it out and see where I am going wrong? Would appreciate that a lot. Thank you!

Comment: If you're new to promises, you should probably start with something simple, make it work, then add complexity.  What you're doing right now is rather complex.  If you need an introduction to working with promises and async/await (which you really shouldn't mix in the same function except where required), start with these videos.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: @DougStevenson Will do, thanks!

Comment: @DougStevenson Your videos were a great help, thank you! I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cleaned up my code and solved my problem, here is how I generated the urls and passed them to the proper URLs by accessing the users UID and postId in the file path:

```
export const generateThumbs = functions.storage
.object()
.onFinalize(async object => {
    const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const userUid = filePath.split('/')[2];
    const sizes = [64, 256];
    const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

    console.log(userUid);

    if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
        console.log('exiting function');
        return false;
      }

    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(tmpdir(), fileName);

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tempFilePath
    }).then(() => {

     sizes.map(size => {      
        const newFileName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}.png`
        const newFileTemp = path.join(tmpdir(), newFileName);
        const newFilePath = `thumbs/${newFileName}`

        return sharp(tempFilePath)
          .resize(size, size)
          .toFile(newFileTemp, () => {

            return bucket.upload(newFileTemp, {
                destination: join(bucketDir, newFilePath),
                metadata: {
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
                  }
            }).then((data) => {
                const file = data[0]
                console.log(data)
                file.getSignedUrl({
                  action: 'read',
                  expires: '03-17-2100'
                }, function(err, url) {
                    console.log(url);
                  if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                  }
                  if (size === 64) {
                    return admin.database().ref('profileThumbs').child(userUid).child(fileName).set({ thumb: url });
                  } else {
                    return admin.database().ref('categories').child(fileName).child('thumb').set(url);
                  }
                })
              })
          })
      })
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
```